# Getting Facebook user from access token using php sdk 3.2.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-access-token

I have a facebook app which I have created to get the user's access token and later use the token to post to the user's wall.

The problem is that after I get the permissions from the user(publish_stream) the `$fb->getUser();` returns 0 even when the user is logged.

If i use     `$fb->getAccessToken();`    it returns App_id|secret.

What is the problem?

Comment: If `getUser()` returns 0 it could mean that you have not yet authenticated your user...

Comment: I go to the facebook login page, login and then it asks for permission i click allow and i redirect to a page on my site . But then it shows getUser as 0. If i check the app setting in my facebook account it shows that i have added the app it also shows that i have given the publish_stream permission..